# Using stash and eclipse, I cannot see a branch I created in the Stash UI in the git view in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, git-stash

So I created a branch in the stash UI but I cannot see it on the list of Remote Tracking branches in the Git Repositories eclipse add-on.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: to see remote branche you have to push the branch and fetch.

Answer (score 0):

to see remote branches you have to perform "fetch".